# Comments sometimes overlap in new review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

I saw this one for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/168539). The second line of the comment overlaps with the first line.

> [image: screenshot]

It happens in Firefox and Chrome; I haven't checked with other browsers.

Comment: It happens whenever the comment wrap to more than one line, as the anchor element has padding plus background color.

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed now. Or at least, the level of overlap is identical to that on the regular question page. Thanks for the report.